# Присвоение TextBlock данных из сокета. SocketIODotNet C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, socket.io, socketio-client

Я пишу программу используя SocketIODotNet. Хочу TextBlock присвоить переданное значение из сокета. Подскажите как это сделать?
Пример кода:

```
socket.On("calling", (data) =>
{
    time_call.Text = data;
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `data` - это object. Если вы уверены, что там string, то переведите просто в нужный тип (например `data.toString()`). Судя по [официальному](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/blob/master/test/SocketIoClientDotNet.Tests/ClientTests/ServerConnectionTest.cs#L84) варианту, так  оно и работает.

Answer (score 0):

`time_call.text = data.tostring();`